# Menu transition while resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

The issue I have is given on the following pen

http://codepen.io/dingo_d/pen/oXBYjW

I have a working menu. In mobile width (<700px) and in normal browser (>1170px).

If you refresh the pen on those sizes, and click on the menu item, everything works fine. On either sizes.

However on resize, the part of the toggle function that will control the animation is not working as it should. This code is inside the `header_toggle()` function

```
        $menu_toggle.on('click', function (e) {
            if ($(window).width()<960) {
                $(this).toggleClass('mobile_open');
                if ($(this).hasClass('mobile_open')) {
                    $navigation.fadeIn().animate({width: '70%'},250);
                } else{
                    $navigation.animate({width: '0' },250).fadeOut();
                }
            } else{
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                    $breadcrumbs_bar.toggle('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 250, function () {
                        $navigation.toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 250).css('display', 'inline-block');
                    });
                } else {
                    $navigation.toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 250, function () {
                        $breadcrumbs_bar.toggle('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 250).css('display', 'inline-block');
                    });
                }
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

It's like that on resize, when you're inside the function, the if statements are not working all the time? Any workaround?

My biggest concern is if someone is on a tablet, and flip it, and is right in between the resolutions, that this issue will happen.

On sizes above 960 px animation that happens is slide up and down, and the class that toggles is `open`, below that you have fade and width animation, and class toggle `mobile_open`.

Just doing it all with css is out of the option, because the slide up and down animation with css (using `transform` property) works only if I have overflow hidden for the container, but if I have a drop down menu, the overflow should be visible.

On resize code:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    toggle_menu();
    header_toggle();
    if ($(window).width()>767) {
        if ($main_header.has($navigation)) {
            $navigation.detach().appendTo('.menu_wrapper');
        }
    } else{
        $navigation.detach().prependTo('body');
    }

});
```

The fiddle has all the jquery code.

Comment: I think you should write code on resize.

Comment: I put this in the function, that I just call on resize. I need to detach the navigation, because once the header has fixed position (on mobile) it's its own container, so the menu won't work. So I detach it, and prepend to body, so that it can freely expand.

Answer (score 0):

I just got finished writing a menu similar to what you are trying to do.

Take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXZgYR

**isMobile()**

Function to check if the window is in a Mobile resolution.

**setMenuType()**

Function to add / remove a class to the navbar on page load and when the window resize.

**windowResize()**

I included the setTimeout so that the function runs only when the window is done resizing.

Hopefully this helps you get an idea of how to do a mobile / desktop navbar/menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isMobile() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  setMenuType();     

  function setMenuType() {
    if (isMobile()) {
      $('nav').removeClass('desktop');
      $('nav').addClass('mobile');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('mobile');
      $('nav').addClass('desktop');
    }
  }

  var resizeId;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(setMenuType(), 500);
  });
});
```